# reversed string not being returned in a c function in program of infix to prefix

Tags: c, string, data-structures, stack, prefix-notation

Below is the code for infix to prefix conversion. My code works fine until the use of `reverse` function where it does not print any string after copying. I have tried using a `for` loop to copy the reversed string but the outcome remains the same and the program terminates without giving proper output. Print statements in the `reverse` function work before copying but not after that. Could anyone let me know where the problem is?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

struct stack{
    int size;
    int top;
    char *arr;
};

void display(struct stack *ptr)
{
    if(ptr->top == -1)
    {
        printf("Stack is Empty");
    }
    else
    {
        for(int i = ptr->top ; i>=0 ; i--)
        {
            printf("Element: %d\n",ptr->arr[i]);
        }
    }
}

int isEmpty(struct stack *ptr)
{
    if(ptr->top == -1)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

int isFull(struct stack *ptr)
{
    if(ptr->top == ptr->size - 1)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

void push(struct stack *ptr,int data)
{
    if(isFull(ptr))
    {
        printf("Stack Overflow");
    }
    else
    {
        ptr->top = ptr->top + 1;
        ptr->arr[ptr->top] = data;
    }    
}

char pop(struct stack *ptr)
{
    if(isEmpty(ptr))
    {
        printf("Stack Underflow");
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        char ch = ptr->arr[ptr->top];
        ptr->top = ptr->top - 1;
        return ch;
    }    
}

char stackTop(struct stack *ptr)
{
    return ptr->arr[ptr->top];
}

int isOperator(char a)
{
    if(a == '+'|| a == '-'|| a == '*'|| a == '/')
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

int precedence(char a)
{
    if(a == '*' || a == '/')
    {
        return 3;
    }
    else if(a == '+' || a == '-')
    {
        return 2;
    }
    else
    {
        return -1;
    }
}

char * reverse(char exp[])
{
    int l = strlen(exp);
    int j = 0;
    char temp[l];

    for(int i=l-1;i>=0;i--,j++)
    {
        temp[j] = exp[i];
    } 
    
    
    
    temp[j] = '\0';
    printf("prefix is %s",temp);
    
    strcpy(exp,temp);
    // for(int i=0;i<=l;i++)
    // {
    //     exp[i] = temp[i];
    // }
    printf("prefix is %s",exp);
    return exp;
}

char * infix_prefix(char *infix)
{
    struct stack *sp = (struct stack *) malloc(sizeof(struct stack));

    sp->size = 100;
    sp->top = -1;
    sp->arr = (char *) malloc(sp->size * sizeof(char));
    char *prefix = (char *) malloc((strlen(infix+1)) * sizeof(char));

    
    infix = reverse(infix);
    

    int i=0; 
    int j=0;
    
    while(infix[i] != '\0')
    {
        if(infix[i] == ')')
        {
            push(sp,infix[i]);
            i++;
        }
        else if(infix[i] == '(')
        {
            while(!isEmpty(sp) && stackTop(sp) != ')')
            {
                prefix[j] = pop(sp);
                j++;
            }
            if(!isEmpty(sp))
            {
                pop(sp);
                i++;      
            } 
            else
            { 
                printf("Incorrect Expression");
                exit(0); 
            }
        }
        else if(!isOperator(infix[i]))
        {
            prefix[j] = infix[i];
            i++;
            j++;
        }
        else if(isOperator(infix[i]))
        {
            while(!isEmpty(sp) && precedence(infix[i])<=precedence(stackTop(sp)))
            {
                prefix[j] = pop(sp);
                j++; 
            }     
            push(sp,infix[i]);
            i++;   
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Incorrect expression");
            exit(0);
        }
    }

    while(!isEmpty(sp) && stackTop(sp) != '(')
    {
        prefix[j] = pop(sp);
        j++;
    }

    if(stackTop(sp) == ')')
    {
        printf("Incorrect expression");
        exit(0);
    }

    
    prefix = reverse(prefix);
    
    prefix[j] = '\0';
    
    return prefix;
}

int main(void)
{
    char *infix = "(x-y/z-k*d)";

    printf("prefix is %s",infix_prefix(infix));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: did it even compile if it has compile then did get any warning or error at runtime, or did you get compilation error?

Comment: Fyi, this is quite literally what a debugger is made for. I'd start by realizing the string pointed to by `infix` in `main` is immutable, but you're stomping on it anyway in `reverse`. Changing `char *infix` to `char infix[]` will probably get you further than you are right now.

Answer (score 1):

The `reverse` indeed has a problem: the `temp` array is defined with a length of `l`: that's not long enough to store the null terminator at `temp[j]` after the loop, causing undefined behavior.

There are more problems:

- `char *prefix = (char *) malloc((strlen(infix+1)) * sizeof(char));` does not allocate enough space for a copy of `infix`. You should write `char *prefix = malloc(strlen(infix) + 1);`
- `infix = reverse(infix);` will crash because the argument to `infix_prefix` is a string literal which must not be modified. You should declare the argument as `const char *infix` and make a modifiable copy with `strdup()` if reversing is really needed, which I doubt very much.

Here is a modified version of `reverse` that performs the reverse operation in place:

```
char *reverse(char exp[]) {
    int i = 0;
    int j = strlen(exp);

    while (j-- > i) {
        char c = exp[j];
        exp[j] = exp[i];
        exp[i++] = c;
    }
    return exp;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, I changed memory allocation method for each array and gave it a specific size big enough for program to work and the program works fine now.